# How to repeat Blend If 'Underlying Layer' Photoshop blending with a mask

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blending

I'm trying to repeat a Blend If 'Underlying Layer' blending with a mask. I have a background layer with some shapes and an orange layer:

[image]

I set the dark levels of Blend If to 90/130:

[image]

I've tried two ways: using levels (didn't work, especially for cases when the little slider thing isn't separated) and using a gradient map. For the gradient map I've set markers to be at `90/255 ~ 35%` and `130/255 ~ 51%`

[image]

The resulting mask:

[image]

However the result is slightly more transparent (there's a visible seam between two versions):

[image]

That could be caused by the fact that gradient map can only use integer locations in 0..100 range while the Blend If mask uses a 0..255 range: the actual locations should've been `35.29%` and `50.98%`. Or maybe I've made a mistake with something. I wonder if anyone has any suggestions on how to repeat the result of this Blend If operation so that it'd be completely the same.

[Here's the .psd](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ee5nlndj6b37thl/test_scene.psd?dl=1) if anyone wants to try.

Comment: Oh I think I made the image with the seam confusing: there's no seam in the images, those are two results put together against each other: the top part is the orange layer with the gradient map I got and the bottom part is the original Blended If layer. I put them together to better illustrate a slight difference. I've updated the image.

Comment: Ahh.. yes clearer now :)

Comment: I'm not sure I get what the problem is. Why not use the gradient map if it works better?

Comment: @Luciano the Gradient Map I'm generating gives me a _slightly_ different transparency gradient and I want to get _exactly the same_ transparency gradient

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think my approach was correct, but default Photoshop Gray color correction (`Dot Grain 20%`) was making additional modifications to the mask gamma. Setting Gray Working Color Space to `Gray Gamma 2.2` before applying the gradient mask has fixed the difference between Blend-ed If and masked layer.

update: nope, doesn't give 100% correct results

Comment: What? I never thought about Gray Working Space affecting things like this! I downloaded your file and see how choosing *Gray Gamma 2.2* gets you closer than *Dot Gain 20%*,  but they still don't look exactly similar to me.

Comment: @Wolff in a document with white BG create a gray (50% brightness) layer and select+cut it. Fill the empty layer with black color, add a layer mask and paste that copied gray layer in the mask. Sample the resulting gray color. You'd expect that it will have 50% brightness (100% black - 50% values of gray mask), but it will be 59%: due to gray correction gamma. With Gray Gamma 2.2 the result will be correct

Comment: @Wolff however yes, in the end the gamma didn't resolve the issue I have. Depending on BlendIf values I still see the difference between the blended and masked layers. So I won't accept my answer :D

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not exactly sure why or how the math isn't working exactly, but I was able to get it to work with a minor adjustment.  I DID adjust my Gray Working Color Space to the Gray Gamma 2.2

Other than that, the only adjustment I made was to change the Gradient map overlay by 1% either way.  So instead of setting for 35% / 51%, I set for 34% / 52%.

[image: Black Slider]
[image: White Slider]

Final Result:

[image: Final result]

Showing Divide Line:

[image: Showing line]

Since changing the Working Space profile changed the results so much, I played with a couple different settings and got different results every time.  Using the default 20% Dot Gain profile was way off as you saw.  The 30% dot gain was better, but still not perfect.

[image: 30% Dot Gain Profile]

With all of that in mind, using the canned Gamma 2.2 profile and adjusting your match by 1% out seems to be the best solution. I tried the match for a couple different Blend If positions, and the shift by 1% isn't exact, so you would need to check what exact percentage you need if you change the original Blend If.

Comment: Thank you for reply. So if I understand you were eyeballing the gradient map? I want to do the whole thing with a script so manual adjustments aren't ideal... I have another idea: maybe I should modify colors of the gradient map, will try that layer

Comment: Not exactly eyeballing, but changing the settings slightly one way or the other to see if I could get it to match.  are you always using the same color / look?  If so, you should be able to script it, or is it something that will be changing all the time?

Comment: changing the colors of the gradient map isn't the worst idea either.